# How to flash a zip file without signature verification?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have lenovo a3300-gv running android kit-kat. I tried to flash a .zip file in it using flashify. But it fails to flash as signature verification fails. I read some articles stating to flash in CWM/TWRP recovery to avoid this error. But I can't get custom recovery for my device. So, is there other way to flash in stock recovery without signature verification?

Comment: Unless you could somehow get the manufacturer's private key to sign it, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid no (no easy one). As you have no custom recovery for your HW platform there is chance you can't rebuild a firmware for your phone. Bypassing this signature is possible only by modifying the source (actually this is what is done in teamwin or clockworkmod recoveries).